# Contour integral of non analytic exponential function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The value of the integration of the function $f(z)$ over the circle of radius 3 centered at $z=1$, where

$f(z) = e^{\frac{-1}{(z-1)^2}}$

this function has a pole at $z=1$ of $2$nd order.

I don't understand how the order is only two because when I expand the exponential the power on $(z-1)^2$ in the denominator will be increasing to infinity. Please solve the integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\oint_{|z-1|=3} f(z) dz =\oint_{|z-1|=3}\exp ((z-1)^{-2} ) dz =\oint_{|z-1|=3}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} (z-1)^{-2n} \right)dz=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\oint_{|z-1|=3}(z-1)^{-2n} dz =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(3e^{it})^{-2n} 3ie^{it}dt =0$$

Comment: can you tell about the singularities of the function.